# MySql for searching available car with date range getting same id with different value

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need help to show all available car with this code.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT kendaraan.* FROM kendaraan 
    LEFT JOIN transaksi ON kendaraan.ID_Kendaraan =    transaksi.ID_Kendaraan  
    WHERE  (Tipe LIKE'%$tipemerk%' OR Merk LIKE '%$tipemerk%') AND ID_Tipe='$tipe'
            AND COALESCE(transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman  NOT BETWEEN '$tglpergi'  AND '$tglkembali', TRUE)
            AND COALESCE(transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian  NOT BETWEEN '$tglpergi'  AND '$tglkembali', TRUE)
            AND COALESCE('$tglpergi'  NOT BETWEEN transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman  AND transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian, TRUE)
            AND COALESCE('$tglkembali'  NOT BETWEEN transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman  AND transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian, TRUE)";       
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

My database for **transaksi** ( transaction ) : ( `Tgl_Peminjaman` is start date , and `Tgl_Pengembalian` is end date )

```
ID_Transaksi | ID_User | ID_Kendaraan | ID_Karyawan | Tgl_Peminjaman | Tgl_Pengembalian | Tgl_Transaksi | Tgl_Kembali | Total_Biaya | Bank | Status_Pembayaran | Denda_Keterlambatan | Status   | Alamat_pengiriman                     | Supir
TR001        | NP002   | KDR001       |             | 2016-11-28     | 2016-11-28       | 2016-11-27    | 0000-00-00  |      500000 | BCA  | Belum Bayar       |                   0 | Diproses | jl. duri kosambi no 414 jakarta barat | Tidak
TR002        | NP002   | KDR001       |             | 2016-11-29     | 2016-11-29       | 2016-11-27    | 0000-00-00  |      500000 | BNI  | Belum Bayar       |                   0 | Diproses | jl. duri kosambi no 414 jakarta barat | Tidak
```

my database for kendaraan ( **vehicle** ) :

```
ID_Kendaraan | ID_Tipe | Merk       | Tipe              | Tahun | CC    | Warna          | KM    | Foto                   | Harga
KDR001       | MBL     | Toyota     | Avanza            | 2016  | 1500  | Hitam          | 3231  | image/KDR001.png       |  500000
KDR002       | MBL     | Toyota     | Avanza            | 2016  | 1500  | Biru           | 2900  | image/AVblue.png       |  450000
KDR003       | MBL     | Toyota     | Avanza            | 2014  | 1500  | Putih          | 2900  | image/AVwhite.jpg      |  400000
KDR004       | MBL     | Toyota     | Avanza            | 2014  | 1300  | Silver Metalic | 2900  | image/AVsilver.png     |  400000
KDR005       | MBL     | Toyota     | Prius             | 2014  | 1300  | White          | 2900  | image/PRwhite.jpg      |  300000
```

The issue is i still getting the same `ID_Kendaraan` with different value. So if i search with start date `"2016-11-28"` and end date "`2016-11-28`", it still showing `ID_Kendaraan with id = KDR001 , Tgl_Peminjaman = 2016-11-29 , and Tgl_Pengembalian = 2016-11-29`.

The output i get :

```
 ID_Kendaraan | ID_Tipe | Merk   | Tipe   | Tahun | CC   | Warna          | KM   | Foto                 | Harga  | Tgl_Peminjaman | Tgl_Pengembalian
 KDR001       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2016  | 1500 | Hitam          | 3231 | image/KDR001.png     | 500000 | 2016-11-29     | 2016-11-29
 KDR002       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2016  | 1500 | Biru           | 2900 | image/AVblue.png     | 450000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR003       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2014  | 1500 | Putih          | 2900 | image/AVwhite.jpg    | 400000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR004       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2014  | 1300 | Silver Metalic | 2900 | image/AVsilver.png   | 400000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR005       | MBL     | Toyota | Prius  | 2014  | 1300 | White          | 2900 | image/PRwhite.jpg    | 300000 | NULL           | NULL
```

The output i want :

```
 ID_Kendaraan | ID_Tipe | Merk   | Tipe   | Tahun | CC   | Warna          | KM   | Foto                 | Harga  | Tgl_Peminjaman | Tgl_Pengembalian
 KDR002       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2016  | 1500 | Biru           | 2900 | image/AVblue.png     | 450000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR003       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2014  | 1500 | Putih          | 2900 | image/AVwhite.jpg    | 400000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR004       | MBL     | Toyota | Avanza | 2014  | 1300 | Silver Metalic | 2900 | image/AVsilver.png   | 400000 | NULL           | NULL
 KDR005       | MBL     | Toyota | Prius  | 2014  | 1300 | White          | 2900 | image/PRwhite.jpg    | 300000 | NULL           | NULL
```

So how to get the output i want ?? 
I dont want to show cars that already booked. 
Im sorry for my bad english, my native language is indonesia.

Comment: Um, no thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are typing `NOT BETWEEN` in your query. I think you should simply change this:

```
AND COALESCE(transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman  NOT BETWEEN '$tglpergi'  AND '$tglkembali', TRUE)
AND COALESCE(transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian  NOT BETWEEN '$tglpergi'  AND '$tglkembali', TRUE)
```

to this: (showing booked cars and those with NULL in transaction dates)

```
AND (transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman IS NOT NULL OR transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman  >= '$tglpergi')
AND (transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian IS NOT NULL OR transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian  <= '$tglkembali')
```

or to this: (showing cars with NULL in transaction dates)

```
AND transaksi.Tgl_Peminjaman IS NULL
AND transaksi.Tgl_Pengembalian IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :D , but after i changed it with your code it just showing only one vehicle that has value on transaction.

Comment: mmm, this query shows cars with date of trasaction earlier (or equal)  than maximum and after (or equal) minimum.
Not sure if you need to get only cars with nulled dates?

Comment: well , i need to get all cars that available including null. :D

Comment: I'm sorry , but it still showing cars that already been booked.